# Using the same script to open modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Ok so I am designing a website for a magazine and the function below is to open a modal where the user can view the selected piece. I am having some trouble as I want to use this script more than once in the same file. I feel like there is a simple answer, as I have tried to rename variables and such but it hasn't worked. Obviously it won't work c+p'd over and over, so I'm just looking for a way to adapt it respectively. Thanks!

HTML is a basic modal form with the respective variables below, but I'm having some trouble putting it in here, so here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/dugugw

Below Is the script...

```
function = modal(); {
    // Split Ends 
    // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think what you need are parameters to your modal function. modal('modalID', 'btnId'){... then when you say var btn = document.getElementById(btnId); That way the modal function can be used for any modal element & button combination.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all the buttons you want to open the modal.
Then add the on click event handler to all the buttons.

```
<button type="button" class="modal-button" ....

// Get the buttons that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClass("modal-button");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btns.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: So in the code above I would add a class of modal-button to each button I want to open it?